# C++ std::filesystem::directory_iterator cout with additional quotes?

Tags: c++, filesystems

I have a query regarding `filesystem` and `directory_iterator`.

Here is a simple test code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>


int main()
{
    
    std::string path = ".";
    for(const auto &entry: std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
        std::string path_string = entry.path();
        std::cout << path_string << " " << path_string.size() << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Running this code produces output like this

```
"./main.cpp"
./main.cpp
10
```

It appears to be the case that doing an implicit conversion from the returned type of `entry.path()` to the type taken by `cout.operator<<` adds additional `" "` characters around the output, whereas converting directly to a `std::string` object, this does not happen.

Why is this? Is this a C++ 17 bug?

Answer (score 1):

It is intended, see [`std::filesystem::path::operator <<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt)

> Performs stream input or output on the path p. [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) is used so that spaces do not cause truncation when later read by stream input operator.

Comment: I don't like this design decision